# How to use "ax.twinx()" with a loop?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make subplots with 6 different vehicles with two columns having different scales, but I can't make `ax.twinx()` to run properly.

I have a dataframe with 6 unique vehicle types (string) each with their yearly frequency (float) and volume (float). The columns frequency and volume have different scales, e.g. frequency 0.02 and volume 300.

The dataframe has DatetimeIndex with 450 entries from 2026 to 2100 with three columns (vehicle type, frequency and volume) with one row for each year.

```html
Year,vehicle,frequency,volume    
2026-01-01,1,0.00015675840228895915,7.797197712316518
2026-01-01,2,0.000603031835938556,4.274152055060224
2026-01-01,3,0.0034839127394875723,32.4307630450464
2026-01-01,4,0.18361506280569012,1880.2337816435913    
2026-01-01,5,0.195704,1863.0    
2026-01-01,6,0.011633652427816835,235.76892247876808    
2027-01-01,1,0.00015802550299743326,7.860223582707681    
2027-01-01,2,0.0006091576579397212,4.317570483632016    
2027-01-01,3,0.003522641145983795,32.7912748799025    
2027-01-01,4,0.18453313811971853,1889.6349505518083    
2027-01-01,5,0.195704,1863.0    
2027-01-01,6,0.011719286585185128,237.9343612013165    
2028-01-01,1,0.0001593028458631506,7.923758900272702    
2028-01-01,2,0.0006153457083224635,4.36142997277333    
2028-01-01,3,0.0035618000711473584,33.15579429185109    
2028-01-01,4,0.18545580381031715,1899.0831253045676    
2028-01-01,5,0.195704,1863.0    
2028-01-01,6,0.011805965144485972,240.13446565366115
```

Making a figure with two axis (frequency and volume) is straightforward for a single vehicle. It’s also possible to make subplots when you specify the axis index for all vehicle types separately (ax(1,1), ax(2,1) and so on). For two columns with two axis you’ll need to write a lot of code to make a subplot. I have other dataframes with a lot more vehicle types and more frequency and volume columns. There's a need for a more efficient script.

```
import numpy as np 

import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

vehicle_list = list(df.vehicle.unique())

len(vehilce_list)
```

When I run this:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=2, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(12,15))

ax1 = ax1.flatten()

ax2 = ax1.twinx()

for num, v in enumerate(vehicle_list, 0):

    df_tmp = df.loc[df['vehicle'] == v]

    ax1[num].plot(df_tmp.index, df_tmp['frequency'])

    ax2[num].plot(df_tmp.index, df_tmp['volume'])

plt.show()
```

I get an error message when defining the second y-axis.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-6-405d8f15f6c1>", line 3, in <module>
    ax2 = ax1.twinx()

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'twinx'
```

Is there a problem to access the index of `ax2`? How to solve this? 
Any help will be appreciated!