# Loop n-times, adding a new y-data series (different scale) to the same x-axis plot (using ax.twinx())

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to follow these examples,

[Using loops to create multiple matplotlib graphs with dual y-axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60973115/using-loops-to-create-multiple-matplotlib-graphs-with-dual-y-axes)

[How do you plot two different y-axes using a loop with twinx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69866026/how-do-you-plot-two-different-y-axes-using-a-loop-with-twinx)

[How to use "ax.twinx()" with a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57582026/how-to-use-ax-twinx-with-a-loop)

however they don't work for different reasons , for example, `df2` or `region` is not defined, or no answers/comments.  My goal is to read a csv file, and on the fly add columns to a single plot
(They all share the same x-axis, but have different y-axes scales/ranges.)

But when I try to programmatically generate the axes, it has an error because I haven't declared an array of axes to hold the return of twinx():

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Single canvas and axes in which to put all the data
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

#Generate additional Y-axes and save into array for easy access
for i in range (5):
    axIdx [ i ] = ax.twinx()    #ERROR
        
#Loop thru each axis and add csv data, positioning the legend and spines appropriately
time = [0,1,2,3]
y1   = [10,11,12,13]
axIdx[0].plot(time,y1,color="green", label='y1')
axIdx[0].legend(loc='upper right', bbox_to_anchor=(1.2, 1),  ncol=2, borderaxespad=0)
axIdx[0].set_ylabel("y1",color="black")
axIdx[0].tick_params(axis='y',colors="black")
axIdx[0].spines['right'].set_color("black")      

y2   = [7.3,1.2,3.14,88.8]
axIdx[1].plot(time,y2,color="red", label='y2')
axIdx[1].legend(loc='upper right', bbox_to_anchor=(1.4, 1),  ncol=2, borderaxespad=0)
axIdx[1].set_ylabel("y1",color="black")
axIdx[1].tick_params(axis='y',colors="black")
axIdx[1].spines['right'].set_color("black")     

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

How is this normally done?  I tried using a dictionary to import the csv data, but I still need a way to programmatically loop thru the axes.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: first you have to define `axIdx = [None, None, None, None, None]` before you can do `axIdx[i]`. Or you have to define empty list `axIdx = []` and later use `.append()` instead of `[i][` - like `axIdx.append( ax.twix() )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problem with basic knowledge about Python.

You didn't create list.

To use `axIdx[i]` first you have to create list `axIdx = [...]` (with correct number of items).

```
axIdx = [None, None, None, None, None]   # list with 5 elements 

# Generate additional Y-axes and save into array for easy access
for i in range(5):
    axIdx[i] = ax.twinx()
```

But it is more popular to create empty list and use `append()` to add items.

```
axIdx = []   # empty list

# Generate additional Y-axes and save into array for easy access
for i in range(5):
    axIdx.append( ax.twinx() )
```

---

Full working code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Single canvas and axes in which to put all the data
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

#axIdx = [None, None, None, None, None]

# Generate additional Y-axes and save into array for easy access
#for i in range (5):
#    axIdx[i] = ax.twinx()
        
axIdx = []

#Generate additional Y-axes and save into array for easy access
for i in range (5):
    axIdx.append(ax.twinx())
        
# Loop thru each axis and add csv data, positioning the legend and spines appropriately
time = [0,1,2,3]

y1   = [10,11,12,13]
axIdx[0].plot(time,y1,color="green", label='y1')
axIdx[0].legend(loc='upper right', bbox_to_anchor=(1.2, 1),  ncol=2, borderaxespad=0)
axIdx[0].set_ylabel("y1",color="black")
axIdx[0].tick_params(axis='y',colors="black")
axIdx[0].spines['right'].set_color("black")      

y2   = [7.3,1.2,3.14,88.8]
axIdx[1].plot(time,y2,color="red", label='y2')
axIdx[1].legend(loc='upper right', bbox_to_anchor=(1.4, 1),  ncol=2, borderaxespad=0)
axIdx[1].set_ylabel("y1",color="black")
axIdx[1].tick_params(axis='y',colors="black")
axIdx[1].spines['right'].set_color("black")     

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!  I forgot that you can declare/create an empty list with no type.  This is perfect!